# Autodidactic as a Verb

Tags: verbs

Is there an equivalent use of Autodidactic as a verb? Such as "John is an autodidactor". I couldn't find "autodidactor" or "Autodidact Eclipse RCP so I am better educated about how to use Eclipse RCP" as if it were a to-do item.

I am trying to express the idea of self-taught as a verb:  One can learn things on one's own, but does that mean that one can autodidact things?

Comment: I think you mean an "agent noun" (i.e. "autodidactor")  rather than a verb. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_noun

Comment: @Urbycoz: Good point. I couldn't see why OP thought "autodidactor" involved any usage as a verb, but I think you have identified the [false] chain of reasoning.

Comment: I am a self-taught Eclipse RCP user.

Comment: I was thinking autodidaction. As in "I am capable of autodidaction."

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not using it as a verb.

Comment: Are you looking for a word like *autodidactor* (someone who does it) or for the **act** of autodidacting? This question isn't clear. [So I'm counteracting the +1 of whoever thought it was.]

Comment: So far as I know, the word for a self-taught person is *autodidact*.

Comment: In fact, because it's not clear, I'm putting on hold.

Answer (score 4):

The root word here is the adjective [didactic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/didactic), meaning *instructive* (sometimes, particularly of morals), which can be pluralised to give a noun meaning *the art or science of teaching* (the alternative being *didacticism*).

There are no verb forms associated with this root, but it can take the prefix *auto-* (Greek, *self, same*). Thus an [autodidact](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/autodidactic) is *one who teaches [or more usually, has taught] himself*.

So you don't say "John is an autodidactor" because John is an autodidactic.

A common expression used by people who don't know/like such relatively obscure words is to say "John studied at the University of Life", which gives a clue as to why we don't really need *autodidact* to function as a verb - the relevant verb is usually just *live [every day of your life as a learning experience]*.

I suspect OP would like *autodidactic* to have more the sense of *solitary home study*, but since the word is more evocative of *dispensing teaching* than *absorbing learning*, I feel this extension of meaning is unlikely to catch on. A reasonable alternative for OP's context is..

**Teach myself Eclipse RCP so I know better how to use it.**

or perhaps **Learn about..., Study...,** or **Bone up on...** (that last is somewhat informal, but does perhaps imply "by my own efforts" more strongly).