# Connotation of term autodidact

Tags: connotation, nuance

I would like to know if **autodidact** has a positive, negative, or neutral connotation behind it.

These questions asking about usage imply:

#### A neutral connotation:

- [Autodidactic as a Verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/35543/20511)
- [What would you call a person who is not a student, but takes interest in exploring academic topics?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/50579/20511)
- [Self-Learner vs Self-Taught vs Autodidact](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/111203/20511)  *most answers*

#### A positive connotation:

- [What word describes a person who never went to college, but is very successful, and well learned?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/130638/20511)

#### A (slight) negative connotation:

- https://english.stackexchange.com/a/111205/20511  *Slightly negative due to context?*
- ["Deliberate recluse" or "deliberately reclusive"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/46749/20511)  *negative due to association with "deliberately reclusive"*
- [Is "autodidact" too obscure to use in a résumé?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/69233/20511)  *negative due to obscurity*

Comment: How are you using it?

Comment: I'm not.  I ran across it in a question on Programmers.  My initial take is that it was used in an ambiguous context.  I couldn't tell if they were trying to dish out a left-handed compliment or they were "merely stating facts"

Comment: Answering the last example, *If you have to ask . . .*

Comment: @DavidM - this is the sentence.  "I believe the framework was developed internally because the engineer in question is an autodidact, and that at this time he didn't knew a framework which will satisfy his need."  And I don't mean to derail my primary question, but my initial take was negative and then mollified to neutral.

Comment: I meant, if you have to ask if it's too big of a word to use on your resume . . . it is.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you've answered your own question above.  It largely has to do with context.  There is certainly no inherent connotation to the word other than self-taught.

There are definitely situations where being self-taught is positive, negative, and neutral.

For instance:  A 15 year-old piano prodigy being an autodidact has an extremely positive connotation.  (Some would call him a genius . . .)

A neurosurgeon who is an autodidact, well, that might be construed as negative.  (Most would call him a criminal.)

I'm a serious amateur photographer who is an autodidact.  I'd say it's fairly neutral.  (The judgement would be withheld pending the quality of my work.)

**Note** I strongly prefer *self-taught* in my own usage.

Comment: Why is a "neurosurgeon who is an autodidact" bad?

Answer (score 1):

To answer based on the usage I would say it has a slight negative connotation.  First, this is not an informal word I would hear in a conversation.  Second, if I were "self-taught", then using the word to reference myself is kind of like saying, "Not only am I self-taught, but I know big words too."

Comment: I don't know that this negative connotation is inherent to the word itself.  Rather, it is your perception of the usage of a "big-word" that has the negative connotation (I'm not saying I like it, either . . .).  If you read the word autodidact written about someone else, I don't know that you'd have the same reaction.

Comment: It is the word that would rub me a certain way.  Who would use that word to describe them self?

Comment: I don't disagree that self-taught is more pleasant.  (I refrained from using *mellifluous* here, so as to avoid rubbing you any way . . .)  But, I don't think the word impacts negatively on the person you use it to describe.  I think that is the meaning of connotation in this case.  As is said, "Big words, small mind."  But, I don't think the poor guy you hang this label on is any worse for wear.

Comment: @DavidM - Your last comment, is my whole point.

Comment: I agree with you on that front.  But, again, I think it's not a connotation.  Rather, you just dislike the word.